# What value to use for setWriteQueueMaxSize() in vertx

Tags: java, vert.x

I am writing code to asynchronously copy file from one to another while handling backpressure.

I know that there is a convenient class `Pump` which does the copy job, but, I am doing copy work manually as I want to transform the data before I write it to destination.

To handle backpressure, I am using below code

```
            fileRead.handler(buffer -> {
                fileWrite.write(applyTransform(buffer));
            //check if reader is out of capacity for taking more data
                if(fileWrite.writeQueueFull()){
                  System.out.println("writing queue full:");
                    //this pauses file handler from being called
                    fileRead.pause();
        //Once, the writer is ready to accept more data, let it take up more
                    fileWrite.drainHandler(done -> {
                      System.out.println("write queue drained, so resuming now...");

        //allow file reader handler to resume so, that it accepts incoming data 
                        fileRead.resume();
                    });
                }
            });
```

My question is only regarding `fileWrite.writeQueueFull()` as the [api documentation](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/) of `WriteStream` says

> This will return true if there are more bytes in the write queue than
>   the value set using setWriteQueueMaxSize(int)

The question is how do determine int value for `setWriteQueueMaxSize(int)`